# XML Library able to read from XML but not write/changes to XML

Tags: robotframework

I am writing a test case using RobotFramework and the XML Library where I want to change the text of an element.

I am also using DataDriver to fill in my arguments.

I have some basic code where I want to change the text element and afterwards I am attempting to confirm that the change was correctly done:

```
Test to Change one value in XML
[Arguments]     ${DEBMEMRID}        ${DEBBANKID}        ${DEBCODEBRAND}     ${DEBCOMPID}        ${DEBCOMMAWLID}     ${CREMEMID}     ${CREMEMTYPE}       ${CREBANKID}        ${CRECODEBRAND}     ${CRECOMPID}        ${CRECOMID}
${root}=        Parse XML       ${XMLFile}
Set Element Text      ${XMLFile}        ${DEBMEMRID}       xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID
Element Text Should Be      ${XMLFile}      ${DEBMEMRID}         xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID
${text}     Get Element Text        ${XMLFile}      xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID
```

So the "Element Text Should Be" manages succesfully to read the XML as by text case goes into failed.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestID 2                                                              | FAIL |
400003 != 400001
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So in the XML the original value is 400003 and the value I want to add is 400001.

This is the logging/output for this part of the code:

```
    <kw library="XML" name="Parse Xml">
<doc>Parses the given XML file or string into an element structure.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>${XMLFile}</arg>
</arguments>
<assign>
<var>${root}</var>
</assign>
<msg level="INFO" timestamp="20190827 12:54:54.202">${root} = &lt;Element 'Document' at 0x03850240&gt;</msg>
<status starttime="20190827 12:54:54.201" status="PASS" endtime="20190827 12:54:54.203"></status>
</kw>
<kw library="XML" name="Set Element Text">
<doc>Sets text and/or tail text of the specified element.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>${XMLFile}</arg>
<arg>${DEBMEMRID}</arg>
<arg>xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID</arg>
</arguments>
<status starttime="20190827 12:54:54.203" status="PASS" endtime="20190827 12:54:54.204"></status>
</kw>
<kw library="XML" name="Element Text Should Be">
<doc>Verifies that the text of the specified element is ``expected``.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>${XMLFile}</arg>
<arg>${DEBMEMRID}</arg>
<arg>xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID</arg>
</arguments>
<msg level="FAIL" timestamp="20190827 12:54:54.205">400003 != 400001</msg>
<status starttime="20190827 12:54:54.204" status="FAIL" endtime="20190827 12:54:54.206"></status>
</kw>
```

Is there something like permissions that need to be set up in order for the XML Library to be able to adapt the file? How can I set does up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${root}=        Parse XML       ${XMLFile}
Set Element Text      ${root}        ${DEBMEMRID}       xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID
Element Text Should Be      ${root}      ${DEBMEMRID}         xpath=./Payment/Payment_Instruction/Debited_Party/Member/Member_ID
```

After parsing the XML to `${root}` you shall set the element text and do the comparison for `${root}` as well. In your example you parsed the `${XML_FILE}` into `${root}` but directed all the subsequent keywords against the `${XML_FILE}`.

If you want to overwrite the old XML file with the new information you may do so with the keyword `Save Xml`:

```
Save XML  ${root}  ${XML_FILE}
```

The full Robot Framework XML library documentation can be found here:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html

Comment: i am using the library but didn't think the reference to ${root} was needed the whole time. Thank you.